# How can I play a .wav (or any other kind of file) file? Like actual audio output

Tags: python, macos, audio, wav, osx-mountain-lion

how can I play an .wav file that is in the same directory? Any help would be appreciated! But make sure it works with Mac OS X Mountain Lion. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide anything that shows you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [`Pygame`](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/MacLionCompile):

```
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.Sound('sound.wav').play()
```

read more here: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html